# FTP upload works on Virtual Machine but not on a real phone Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

My goal is to upload 6 images to a ftp server, from my kotlin Android Studio app.
My code work's on a AVD Virtual machine with ALMOST the same specs than
my real Huawei P30 Lite phone.

Here is the catch; On my phone, sometimes, it doesn't send any files, and sometimes 2 or 3 and sometimes with awful quality.

I've tried 4 different upload code, and no differences.
Does the problem come from `var bytesIn = ByteArray(4096)`?
Maybe internet stability?
It works perfectly for 10 / 50 ko jpg Images but weirdly for 12MB pictures.
The code comes partially from Java translated in Kotlin by Android studio.

Here is my threads:

```
class FTPthread():Thread(){
//767|1652&365|748
var urisArr :File?=null
var num :Int?=null
var infoos :TextView?=null




override fun run() {
    val server = "ftpupload.net"
    val port = 21
    val user = "MYUSERNAME"
    val pass = "MYPASSWORD"
    val ftpClient = FTPClient()
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server, port)
        ftpClient.login(user, pass)
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)

        var inputStream: InputStream = FileInputStream(urisArr)



        var secondRemoteFile = "/htdocs/rbks/code0 $num.jpg"
        inputStream = FileInputStream(urisArr)
        var outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile)
        var bytesIn = ByteArray(33554432)
        var read = 0
        while (inputStream.read(bytesIn).also { read = it } != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read)
        }
        inputStream.close()
        outputStream.close()
        var completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand()
        if (completed) {
            infoos!!.text = ((infoos!!.text).toString().toInt() +1).toString()

            if((infoos!!.text).toString().toInt() == 6){
                infoos!!.text  = "Finished uploading with sucess, waiting for callback"
            }
        }

    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        //infosTextvar.text="error ("+ ex.message+")"
        println("Error: " + ex.message)
        ex.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        sleep(10_500)
    }
    try {
        if (ftpClient.isConnected) {
            ftpClient.logout()
            ftpClient.disconnect()
        }
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}

}

class mainThread():Thread(){

public var testuri :File?=null
public var testuri1 :File?=null
public var testuri2 :File?=null
public var testuri3 :File?=null
public var testuri4 :File?=null
public var testuri5 :File?=null
public var pos :File?=null
public var infoos :TextView?=null

var photos = arrayOf(testuri, testuri1, testuri2, testuri3, testuri4, testuri5)



override fun run() {
    infoos!!.text  = "0"

    for (i in 0..5) {
        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(1000_000L)

        var t1=FTPthread()
        t1.urisArr=photos[i]
        t1.num=i+1
        t1.infoos=infoos
        t1.start()
    }


}
}
```

What I have a var rbks_files which is an array of Files.
I call this after I took the last photo

```
var t1=mainThread()
t1.photos=rbks_files
t1.pos=pFileSaved
t1.infoos=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.infos)
t1.start()
```

Comment: If you're seeing awful quality, your problem is something else.  FTP uploads files, it doesn't know that they're images or encode them.  What you send is what you get.  The only thing that could cause problems there is if you're in text mode instead of binary, in which case it can screw up line conversions and corrupt files.

Comment: `println("Error: " + ex.message)` You mean: `println("IOException: " + ex.message)` Well wat did it print?

Comment: Your code only uploads one file. Where is the loop to upload more?

Comment: It looks you are starting all thread/uploads at once. Better: only start the next upload when an upload is done.